# use session made from ajax inside blade laravel 4.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

hi so im making a session via ajax when a certain button is clicked here is the code

```
function cModal(id)
    {

        alert(id);

        $.ajax({
          method: 'post',
          url: 'http://localhost/dummy/app/putSession.php',
          data: {
            'dID': id
          },
          success: function() 
          {
            alert(id);
          }
        });
    }
```

it is successfull because it alerts the id inside the `success:function()`
in my `putSession.php` file here is how i did it

```
<?php
session_start();
$tId = $_POST['dID'];
$_SESSION["sID"] = $tId;
exit();
```

?>

but the thing is i can't access it inside my blade file im calling it like this

```
<div class="modal-content">
    <div class="row rowMarg">
    <?php session_start(); ?>
        @if(Session::has('sID'))
            {{ Session::forget('sID') }}
            <h6>Information.</h6>


        @else
            <h6>File details not found.</h6>
        @endif
    </div>
</div>
```

it just goes to the `file details not found`
any idea what im doing wrong? thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

use laravel session like

```
      $request->session()->put('user', 'value');
      $request->session()->get('user', 'value');
      $request->session()->push('user.teams', 'developers');
```

for more https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/session

Comment: hi! i really wanted to use laravel 5.1 but i have just inherited this project and it already uses 4.2